# Installing plugin for Emacs

Tags: plugins, emacs, installation

I'm using [this](http://bruda.ca/emacs/prolog_mode_for_emacs) instructional page to install a Prolog plugin for Emacs, and it says the following:

```
In a nutshell, place the downloaded file where Emacs can see it, 
and insert into your ~/.emacs or ~/.xemacs/init.el the following 
lines:
```

What does it mean to place a file where Emacs can see it, and how do I insert into ~/.emacs?

Comment: Please contact the maintainer of that web-page to update his text, since the prolog.el distributed with Emacs is now that package (with some additional enhancements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Place a file where Emacs can see it" means placing the file `prolog.el` in a [**directory** devoted to additional per-user Emacs-specific files](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsDotD), e.g. in a subdirectory of `~/.emacs.d/` (like `~/.emacs.d/elisp`) and if needed, [adding that directory to`load-path`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath).

The other instructions refer to modifying the [standard Emacs initialization **file**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), e.g. `~/.emacs.d/init.el.` Insert the lines given in those instructions into your own Emacs initialization file, then save the file and restart Emacs.

Comment: Hi Keith, can you give me the terminal command for inserting text into a file?

Comment: @KeithFlower `~/.emacs.d/" is not in the load-path on purpose.  It contains configuration files for packages very frequently names the same as the package itself.  So manually adding it to your load-path is actually very much a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks, I meant use of `~/.emacs.d/` as example of a (parent) directory for plugins as indicated explicitly in the instructions I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distribution, it may be possible that a prolog-mode
is already shipped. If you open a prolog file, check the modeline (the
thing at the bottom) says `prolog` somewhere, you're good to go. Maybe
it didn't associate correctly, try `M-x` (Alt + x) and type
`prolog-mode`, hit enter. Now `prolog` should appear in the modeline.
If it doesn't go on and install the file. Otherwise you have a junk of
software on your computer you'll have to update by hand.

Comment: Emacs does come with a Prolog mode, but it's not very good. This is a separate plugin. =)

Comment: Nope, it's the same. `1.24` instead of `1.22`. The shipped version has a maintainer in 2010/2011 though. Maybe it's worth the trouble, maybe not.

Comment: No way, I didn't know that. Just heard friends complaining about it a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Sure you could. But I'm not on a Debian-based distro ;-)